# Stargate: Continuum, time travel, people vanish from timeline at different moments

Tags: movie, time-travel, stargate, timeline

In the movie *Stargate: Continuum,* is there an in-universe explanation about why and when Ba'al's failsafe plan was triggered, and why there was a delayed timeline ripple as individuals disappeared at slightly different times? It's been a while since I've seen it, but I believe Vala Mal Doran disappeared first, followed by Teal'c, followed by others at the ceremony. Even if my memory is faulty about Vala going before Teal'c, the other SG-1 members don't disappear, allowing them time to escape through the Stargate.

Obviously, from an external plot-driven perspective, it is more dramatic to have sequential disappearances, and there wouldn't have been a story if the other SG-1 members had also vanished, but is there a canonical, in-universe reason? Also, how did the original Ba'al know that it was time to trigger his failsafe plan and when did he initiate it—before the ceremony, after the team and Jack O'Neill gated in, or at some subsequent point? I can accept the concept that a time change might propagate at a finite speed through the timeline, but Vala, Teal'c and the rest of SG-1 shared the same frame of reference in the timeline and, as far as I can tell, everyone should have disappeared together.

[image]

Comment: I'm unaware of any good reason for it, other than that it drives the plot. If the propogation was identical (or instant), there wouldn't be much of a film

Comment: @Richard I suspect you're right, but that would be disappointing. It strikes me that the creative team should have thought of this. But then every science fiction show must have hundreds of holes like this.

Comment: In this instance, I think we're looking at [Bellisario's Maxim](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BellisariosMaxim), that close examination reveals that that most shows are written by writers on a tight deadline, filmed by directors on a tight budget and acted by actors who stayed up late snorting coke instead of learning their lines. Plot-holes are inevitable and largely unexplained.

Comment: @Richard I like that. I should have known about it before, but at least now I do. Thanks!

Comment: You may also want to refer to the '[MST3K Mantra](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MST3KMantra)'; "It's just a show, relax."

Comment: @Richard - "You may also want to refer to the '[MST3K Mantra](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MST3KMantra)'; "It's just a show, relax."" ..... Says the guy with ~170K rep points on a scifi forum. :-p

Comment: @iMerchant - Ah yes, but I've never fallen into the trap of thinking that these shows are anything other than shows. I admire the craft and artistry that's gone into them and love trying to puzzle out what was in the writer/director/actor's mind but I don't get worked up when my headcanon conflicts with reality.

Comment: @Richard - Just giving you a hard time cuz I like ya. :-) I'm actually impressed with your (as well as DVK & others) breadth of knowledge and detailed answers on all these shows/movies/books/etc that I also enjoy. Because of you and others, this forum has turned into a new guilty pleasure of mine, even though my input here is mostly an attempt at levity here and there as well as trying to think of obscure questions nobody else has thought of yet. lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going with the idea that the people vanished in the order their lives were changed: you see Cam affected last, which would make sense if the Achilles sank/didn't sink in 1939.  Teal'c is around 120 now: if Ba'al picked him up after his father's death, he had to do it over a century ago.  Vala becomes host to Qetesh much later: Qetesh herself indicates that Ba'al acquired her some 50 years ago, and since Vala was his enemy, not Qetesh, we can assume Qetesh has had the same host for all that time.

Comment: That could be the answer. Do you have a copy of the movie? I remember that Vala disappeared first, which, if I understand you, wouldn't work with the vanishing order. Teal'c should have gone first, right? But my memory could be faulty. He may have vanished first, or it may not be clear who went first.